# Problema para hacer juego ahorcado

Tags: java, array, interfaz-gráfica, jframe

Quiero hacer el juego del ahorcado, pero, al introducir una letra para averiguar la palabra, no se muestran las letras, el código es:

```
class enviarLetra implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //String  palabraJugar = palabra.getText();

            String letra = textFieldLetra.toString();
            char letraR = letra.charAt(WIDTH);
            palabraR = palabra.toString();
            char[] vc;
            vc = palabraR.toCharArray();
            char[] ocultoC = new char[palabraR.length()];
            
            boolean existe = false;
            for (int i = 0; i <= palabraR.length()-1; i++) {
               
                    if (vc[i] == letraR){
                         ocultoC[i] = letraR;
                        oculto.setText(palabra.getText().replace(ocultoC[i], letraR));
                       
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        existe = true;
                    }
                

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Has hecho debug para ver el contenido de `letraR`? Qué debería tener `ocultoC`? Dónde es que "no se muestran las letras"? Esto lo usa un JPanel o algo así, supongo...

Comment: te traduzco lo que estás diciendo en tu código dentro del bucle: *Si la letra es igual a la de la cadena, entonces ocultoC es igual a la letra, por texto en oculto coge palabra y cambia ocultoC por letraR, pinta cadena en blanco y si existe*. Ahora la pregunta, si ocultoC ya es igual a la letra, como reemplazas una cosa por otra si ya es lo mismo?